# referencing a subform works fine in access 2007 but not in 2013

Tags: ms-access-2007, subform

Just installed Access 2013 and immediately ran into some problems. 
I am trying to take a value from a textbox on a sub form and show that on the main form. Standard stuff that I have done countless times in Access 2007 without problem. In Access 2013, for some reason, it doesn’t work. I get the error message: #Name?

Then I opened an old database made in Access 2007 and there was no problem. The value of the textbox on the sub form showed up on the main form just as it was supposed to. The syntax was identical to the one not working in the database I made in Access 2013 that didn’t work. Curious!

Then I did a simple copy and paste of the working textbox and guess what? The pasted copy doesn’t work!  The original still works of course. Curiouser and curiouser! How a copied and pasted textbox with syntax and formatting identical to is parent doesn’t work is beyond me.

Syntax working in original textbox on main form: [subformname].[Form]![textboxname]

Syntax not working in copy on main form: [subformname].[Form]![textboxname]

The error message: #Name? suggest that the textbox on the sub form cannot be found. But if it can be found in the original……

I have contacted Office support but while I am waiting maybe someone here has an answer.

So am I an idiot and the solution is really obvious (perhaps the most likely scenario) or is there something more sinister going on here?

Comment: Since you're dealing with different Access versions, check your project's references (from the version which is giving you trouble).  From the VB Editor's main menu, choose Tools->References.  Are any of the checkmarked references labelled as *MISSING*?

Comment: Nope! The first four a checked: Visual Basic for Applications, Microsoft Access 15.0 Object Library, OLE Automation, Microsoft Access 15.0 Access database engine Object Library. They are not labeled as missing. Perhaps some other ref needs to be checked?

Comment: What happens if you run Debug->Compile from the main menu?  Does Access complain about anything in your code?  Do all your standard, class, form, and report modules include `Option Explicit` in their Declarations sections?

Comment: It's not in VBA code. It's in the Control Source of the textbox.

Comment: In that case, what is the Control Source property value?

Comment: [subformname].[Form]![textboxname] which works in the original textbox but not in the copied and pasted one.  Thank you for helping by the way!!

Answer (score 0):

I can get the right value in the textbox using VBA so I am not stuck that way. It would just be interesting to know why it dosen't work when setting control source property in 2010 when it works in 2007.